Delete empty rows before column names start on excel spreadsheet using python
My column names on a spreadsheet start on row 2, row 1 is completely blank. 
When I try to delete it, it also deletes column names on row 2 and only keeps first column name. 
Any idea of what I am doing wrong?
Original file
|          |          |
| Column A | Column B |
| Cell 1   | Cell 2   |
| Cell 3   | Cell 4   |

Expected output



Column A
Column B




Cell 1
Cell 2


Cell 3
Cell 4



Current output



Column A




Cell 1


Cell 3



I have tried: 
openpyxl
sheet.delete_rows(1)

pandas
df = df.drop(index=0)


df = pd.read_excel('file_path', header=1)

can you show the code you tried and that doesn't work?

The code is incomplete.

If you have the following data layout and want to delete the first row;

The following code shown for using Openpyxl and Pandas, is all that's needed.
from openpyxl import load_workbook
import pandas as pd

# Openpyxl
wb = load_workbook('foo.xlsx')

wb['Sheet1'].delete_rows(1)

wb.save('foo_openpyxl.xlsx')


# Pandas
df = pd.read_excel('foo.xlsx')
df.to_excel('foo_pandas.xlsx', header=False, index=False)


For Pandas since row 1 will be the default header, writing back to Excel without the header will remove row 1.
The output from both is the same;


when using openpyxl I get the same result. Seems like it is deleting the first row and then just keeping the first column name and merging all others. (See current output snip  above)
Check if the column exists
if column_name not in column_names:
sheet.delete_rows(1)
workbook.save(file_path)
quit()

That doesn't fully explain what you're doing, for example there is a complete operation missing, i.e. how column_name is determined. However be aware, If you are iterating through the rows and deleting [some] rows as you go, you are going to have problems. When a row(s) is deleted all the rows below it immediately shift up by the number of rows deleted. So rows get skipped if you are looping and checking each row down the Sheet.

on this specific example I am just removing row 1 because column names are on row 2. Column_name is just the name of the first column. It would be equivalent to if 1=1 for testing right now and it is still doing the same. I just moved the "sheet.delete_rows(1) to a line where there is no if and it behaves the same so I am not sure why it is doing that.
file_path = os.path.join(directory, filename)
workbook = openpyxl.load_workbook(file_path)
sheet_names = workbook.sheetnames
sheet = workbook['Data']
sheet.delete_rows(1)
workbook.save(file_path)
exit()

I changed it to using pandas and that one works with adding the sheet name to the to_excel piece:
df = pd.read_excel(filename)
df.to_excel(filename, header=False, index=False, sheet_name='Data')  Thank you!
